# Android ContentProvider Performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, ipc

I'm curious if anyone has done any performance testing on querying a `ContentProvider` via `ContentResolver` vs querying a `SQLiteDatabase` object in the same process. I'm guessing that a `ContentResolver` query passes back a Cursor that communicates with the database through a Binder (Android IPC). This means that if I read the contents of 100 records through the `Cursor` that would result 100 Binder method calls. Are my guesses correct and if so would that be significantly slower than accessing the database in the same process?

Comment: As a side note, I performed a test on an 800MHz android device comparing a calls to local methods against calls to remote methods. Calling a remote method with a simple 26 character String paramater takes about 400 nanoseconds longer than calling a local method. Sending a 10,000 character String paramater takes 2.3 milliseconds longer. Clearly the more data being sent (or received) the longer it will take.

Comment: Something I've learned: Cursors passed by ContentProviders contain a CursorWindow, the CursorWindow is a cached area of the Cursor 2MB in size, most queries will fit in the entire buffer. Thus accessing data from the Cursor usually does not initiate a Binder method call since all the data is already there, however if you attempt to read data outside the CursorWindow in a huge cursor then the Window will need to move and the cache will be resent over the Binder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not done exactly that meassure. What I did was to meassure the performance of multiple inserts via a ContentProvider or directly via a SQLite database.
I inserted around 1000 items (one by one). It was much slower to insert via a ContentProvider. In my test almost 10% slower.

Comment: If you are going to insert 1000 items one-by-one then you would use a `ContentProviderOperation` and perform a `batchInsert`. Inserting 1000 items one-by-one will be incredibly slow no matter what you use, so I wouldn't look into this benchmark too much. In my experience, the difference between "using a `ContentProvider`" and "not using a `ContentProvider`" has never come down to the speed/efficiency with which operations are carried out.

Comment: Depends on use case. If I need to get some specific info (UI theme for example) in less than 100ms, ContentProvider are no good.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definitive answer and results depends on what and how you do it.

For example, I want to share preferences between apps so ContentProvider seems the perfect answer. Yes if I don't mind a longer delay on first read as just connecting to a ContentProvider takes 120ms on a S10+ these days!

So if you have a UI depends on those settings, you'd better copy the preference file between apps (using a ContentProvider) and then read from the file directly otherwise the UI will be delayed before showing with appropriate theme. Fact is the onStart() will have already been called for the newly created activity.

On the opposite side doing DB operations (if done right) will not change much of the results, unless you need to re-connect frequently as it will add a non neglectable overhead.